# Falha ao carregar documento PDF

Tags: php, dompdf

Estou trabalhando com um sistema de ofícios, onde o usuário irá digitar o número do ofício, a pessoa a qual o documento será direcionado e a mensagem, e gostaria que, se os dados fossem adicionados ao banco com sucesso, um *PDF* com as informações inseridas fosse gerado, através da biblioteca *DOMPDF*. Porém, ao executar, é retornado o seguinte erro: "Falha ao carregar documento PDF".
O código é esse:

```
<?php
    include_once("../conexao.php");

    $numero = $_POST["numero"];
    $interessado = $_POST["interessado"];
    $assunto = $_POST["assunto"];       

    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO oficio VALUES ('$numero','$interessado','$assunto');");

    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    require_once ("../dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) != 0){
        $html = "<p>".$numero."</p>";
        $html .= "<p>".$interessado."</p>";
        $html .= "<p>".$assunto."</p>";

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        //echo $html;

        $dompdf->load_html("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Teste - Gerar PDF</h1>".$html);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("teste_pdf.pdf",array("Attachment" => false));
    }
    else{
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/principal.php?link=01'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Não foi possível realizar a abertura do ofício!\");
                </script>";
    }
?>
```

O que poderia ser feito para que o documento seja criado?

Answer (score 1):

Tenho duas sugestões:

- Primeiro tente ver qual o charset do texto que vem do seu banco de dados, pode ser que no banco você esta usando ISO-8859-1 e a lib DOMPDF user UTF-8
- A documentação desta lib diz que HTML mal-formatado pode causar problema (verifique se não tem tag sem fechar, ou usando atributos inválidos) (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#limitations-known-issues).